# VS setup project, populate "textboxes" fields from registry

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I would like to be able to populate for instance the `Textboxes (A)` dialogue fields with data from the registry, instead of the default values I can set in the installer project.

I've looked hard, and the prospects for a solution is grim from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard method for this is to create a registry search with the same name as the property used for your textbox. For this you need to define an entry in [AppSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RegLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tables. Unfortunately I don't think you can edit these tables from VS or if there is a predefined support for adding the search to your project.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. I probably have to provide a Winforms app to get the info. At least we cooked the number of firlds down from all 12 available to just 2. If no answer is posted in the next week, I'll mark yours as answer to close the question.

Comment: I have to concede that there may not be an answer to this. I'm marking it as answered for others to hopefully spend less time on a dead end.